# Use of ._meta Django

Tags: python, django

I want to ask about the use of ._meta in this code ? I didn't find a documentation that explains the use of .meta

```
def resend_activation_email(self, request, queryset):
    """
    Re-sends activation emails for the selected users.

    Note that this will *only* send activation emails for users
    who are eligible to activate; emails will not be sent to users
    whose activation keys have expired or who have already
    activated.

    """
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)

    for profile in queryset:
        if not profile.activation_key_expired():
            profile.send_activation_email(site)
resend_activation_email.short_description = _("Re-send activation emails")
```

Answer (score 7):

`_meta` as the name implies stores the meta data of the model. Say, you want to loop over all the fields of a model, then you can use `model._meta.get_fields()`.

By the way, meta options are covered in the documentation -

[Model Meta options documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/)

Comment: Old question, but just happend to stumble across it.

Would you also happen to know why this attribute is marked as private (i.e. the leading underscore)?

I did find it a bit counterintuitive given it seems to the "normal" way to access model metadata.

Comment: @martyn I suppose they don't want you to access it directly out of the class, but expect you to write a method that accesses them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `._meta` in testing.

Consider the below `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author} {self.title} {self.content}"
```

You could use `._meta` to verify label names of a post (in `test_models.py`) like:

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from blog.models import Post

class TestBlogModels(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        author = User.objects.create(username='TestUser1')
        self.post = Post.objects.create(
                        author=author,
                        title='Test Post Title 1',
                        content='Test content for title 1'
                    )

    ....

    def test_blog_author_label(self):
        author_field = Post._meta.get_field('author').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(author_field, "author")

    def test_blog_title_label(self):
        title_field = Post._meta.get_field('title').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(title_field, "title")

    def test_blog_content_label(self):
        content_field = Post._meta.get_field('content').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(content_field, "content")

    def test_blog_title_max_length(self):
        title_field_length = Post._meta.get_field('title').max_length
        self.assertEqual(title_field_length, 100)

    ...
```

(`verbose_name` strips `django.db.models.fields` to the field speicified in `models.py`)